# Batch renaming files in folder by adding date

Tags: batch-file, rename

I have a batch file that moves some things around and organizes them. I want to add to the end of that batch some code to rename all the files to their same name but the date in addition to the end in only numbers. Maybe I'm bad at searching because I swear this has been covered but I just couldn't find it. So to summarize, I need help writing code that will convert every file in the folder that does not already have the date at the end, to have the date added to the end. So it needs to check whether there are 8 digits at the end and if not then add the date. I'll post my batch file just in case you need to know what I'm doing

```
    rem @echo off
SETLOCAL enableextensions
Set dat=Date
for %%x in (*.pdf) do (
    set "_pdfname=%%x"
    call :doAllWork
)
goto :eof

:doAllWork
ECHO start
start %_pdfname%
TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK
start select.vbs
TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK
start copy.vbs
TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK
for /F %%g in ('
  wmic OS get LocalDateTime /value^|findstr "="
  ') do for /F %%G in ("%%g") do set "_%%G"
echo %_LocalDateTime:~0,14%
type NUL > TextFiles\%_LocalDateTime:~0,14%.txt
start TextFiles\%_LocalDateTime:~0,14%.txt
TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK
ECHO close PDF
start close.vbs
TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK
start window.vbs
TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK
start paste.vbs
TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK
start save.vbs
TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK
start close.vbs
start enter.vbs

move /-y "%_pdfname%" "OldTimesheets\"

TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK
ECHO exit loop
if exist *.pdf (
    goto :eof
) else (
    goto :end
)


:end


cscript MessageBox.vbs "This will be shown in a popup."
```

So at the End all of the new PDFs in OldTimesheets need to be renamed but the old ones will have the date they were put in there.
Thanks ahead of time! This Community is always great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out on my own! I added

```
set str=%date%
echo.%str%
set str=%str:/=%
echo.%str%
```

at the begging and used

```
ren OldTimesheets\%_pdfname% %str%%_pdfname%
```

right after the move line. Works like a charm! Thanks for the help anyways!

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /b *.pdf') do (
    call :doAllWork "%%x"
)
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /b *.pdf') do (
    echo %%x | findstr /r "_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\." >nul
    if errorlevel 1 ren "%%x" "%%~fx_!_LocalDateTime:~0,8!%%~nx"
)
cscript MessageBox.vbs "This will be shown in a popup."
pause
exit

:doAllWork
ECHO start
start %1
TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK & start select.vbs
TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK & start copy.vbs
TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK
for /F "delims== tokens=2" %%g in ('
    wmic OS get LocalDateTime /value ^| find "="
') do set _LocalDateTime=%%g
echo !_LocalDateTime:~0,14!
type NUL > TextFiles\!_LocalDateTime:~0,14!.txt
start TextFiles\!_LocalDateTime:~0,14!.txt
TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK & ECHO close PDF & start close.vbs
TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK & start window.vbs
TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK & start paste.vbs
TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK & start save.vbs
TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK & start close.vbs & start enter.vbs
move /-y "%1" "OldTimesheets\"
TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK & ECHO exit loop
exit /b
```

Notes:

- Replaced direct enumeration of `*.pdf` with `dir /b *.pdf` to prevent possible re-processing of files after they have been renamed.
- Added `SETLOCAL enableDelayedExpansion` to make `_LocalDateTime` change its value at each assignment, also `!` instead of `%` should be used in such case
- Removed `SETLOCAL enableextensions` as it's enabled by default
- Simplified a few things to improve readability

Comment: Why is it opening the PDFs in command prompt? And its not creating new black text documents with the current date and time. I'm not too knowledgeable about batch files so maybe I just don't see it!

Comment: I've just reformatted your code and added the renaming part, that's it.

Comment: My code had that part. Not sure why yours isn't working for me but I do appreciate the help!